# Can Doctrine do a SELECT on tables from more than one database?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

I am trying to move from existing SQL to Doctrine

For example, if I have a query like so:

```sql
SELECT column_list
FROM db1
INNER JOIN db2 ON db1.col=db2.col
INNER JOIN db3 ON db2.col=db3.col
WHERE where_conditions;
```

Can Doctrine be used to match the SQL above?

Currently it appears to me that Doctrine can work with multiple entities *separately*, but I have not found documentation on whether or not Doctrine can *combine* the entities into a single SELECT command.

I presume that there is a workaround which is to use several entities separately, i.e. break up the query above into pieces to where only a single database is involved at any one query, but I would be hesitant to do that if there is a better way.

Comment: found this article that may be helpful https://techpunch.co.uk/development/using-multiple-databases-with-symfony2-and-doctrine2

Answer (score 1):

From [techpunch article](https://techpunch.co.uk/development/using-multiple-databases-with-symfony2-and-doctrine2) it appears to me that you can simply use the "dot" separator in your entity name option, leaving everything else the same.  Hence, you gain ability to use entities as-is, and proper databases will be selected for you.

```php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="database_name.table_name")
 */
class YourEntity
```

Comment: This only works if both databases are on the same server and has the further disadvantage of "hardcoding" the database name into your entities.  Just something to be aware of.

Comment: what can be a disadvantage of hardcoding a database name into an entity?

Comment: Well in normal cases you specify the database name as a configuration item making it easy to change or to point to say a test database.  Hardcoding means that you need to change your code to change the database name.